# Email Body Loop Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to loop through a column (n=96) in my worksheet, when it comes across a value <10 I would like the macro to open outlook and email offset values (four columns across) from the values it found.

I've generated a working example though it seems to be limited to only one example I've tested. I think I am approaching it from the wrong angle.

```
Sub SendReminderMail()
    Dim p As Long
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim MailDest As String

    'If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)

    p = 2

    Do Until Trim$(Cells(p, 1).Value) = ""
        If Cells(p, 1).Value <= 10 Then
            Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutLookMailItem
            .To = "Emailaddress etc"
            .Subject = "Reminder: " & Cells(1, 7).Value
            .Body = Cells(p, 1).Offset(0, 4).Value
            .Display
        End With
        End If
    p = p + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

How do I set it up to loop through all the <10 values and tell it to paste the offset values into the body of the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to split this into two blocks of code.

First block would iterate through rows, check criteria and, if needed, call the second one, so the mail sending Sub, passing by necessary parameters.

Someting similar to the below code:

```
Sub SendReminderMail(ByVal MailSubject As String, mailBody As String)
Dim p As Long
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim MailDest As String

'If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
 With OutLookMailItem
      .To = "Emailaddress etc"
      .Subject = MailSubject
      .Body = mailBody
      .Display
  End With
End Sub

Sub IterateThroughRows()
Dim p As Integer
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim MailSubject As String
Dim mailBody As String

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")

p = 2

Do Until Sht.Cells(p, 1).Value = ""
      If Cells(p, 1).Value <= 10 Then
            mailBody = mailBody + " | " + Sht.Cells(p, 1).Offset(0, 4).Value
      End If
        p = p + 1
Loop

Call SendReminderMail(MailSubject, mailBody)
MailSubject = "Reminder: " & Sht.Cells(1, 7).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very close! Is there away to input the looped data into a single email. This option creates an email per data point found.

Comment: Sorry, my first impression was that you needed a separate email pers instance of value matching <10 criteria. Then you need to save all values into some temporary storage and then push it into email body.

Comment: I have adapted the code so that this goal could be achieved. However, this way you will get all results into a poorly organised structure. I would advise to set your "OutLookMailItem" to .BodyFormat = 2 to change type of an email to HTML. Then you could use HTML magic to format your message nicely. Just add line break tags<br/> where I added this -> " | ".

Comment: If I want the "poorly organised structure option" do I just remove " | ". Doing so and running the code throws a run time error 13 "type mismatch" . I don't know enough to edit the line without more guidance. Sorry

Comment: Hey RonanC, my excuse it should be mailBody = mailBody & " | " & Sht.Cells(p, 1).Offset(0, 4).Value . In VBA you concat strings with & not +.

Comment: Amazing, Thank you so much!